# save all everything

Tags: interface

Would like to not press the *Image → Save All Images* menu before each pressing alt + s.

You can close the Blender and then will be prompted to save the modified images

How to save the .blend + modified images in one click?

It is curious that if you first click *Image → Save All Images*, and then exit the Blender without saving - the changes will be lost.

thank you

[image]